# How do I make parent view clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have `EditText` which should only look like `EditText` and I will set text to it but I cant make it work that if I click on its parent, it should do something what is inside `onClickListener`. But its not working. I tried to block focusability to children but its still working only if I click around the edges of the screen.

Any suggestions?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dateParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/TextInput"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:hint="@string/form_birthDate"
            android:inputType="text">
        </EditText>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to click in `dateParent`? Why doesn't it have paddings or any empty space?

Comment: Yes and it should cover EditText. Its EditText without EditText features. If I click on parent, it will open picker instead. But design and behavior will be same as EditText (it will have hint, move hint above if some text is set there). I just want EditText to not be focusable by user and serve as Button.

Comment: replace edittext with textview if you just want to display the text

Comment: @martin1337, yes, you don't need `EditText` here, set `TextView`. Decorate it as you wish. The behaviour you describe contradicts `EditText`.

Comment: I need EditText because of TextInputLayout behaviour. I want to animate hint. Dont wanna make completely custom component for single usage in entire project.

Comment: @martin1337, does `TextView` inside `TextInputLayout` work similarly to `EditText`? I mean `hint` behaviour.

Comment: Nope that will not work at all. Only TextInputEditText or EditText can be inside